# Jquery method to format the numbers not working on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have written one Jquery method to format the numbers. When i apply this function on textbox it works fine but when i apply the same on span it does not format the values. Please let me know what i am missing.

```
setNumberFormattedInput: function (element) {
            var amount = s.toNumber(element.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
            if (!_.isNaN(amount)) {
                $(element).val(s.numberFormat(amount));
            } else {
                $(element).val(0);
            }
        },
    };
```

Comment: It would need to be `$(element).text(....);` - `.val()` only applies to form controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. `.val()` works on input elements (or any element with a value attribute?) and `.text()` will not work on input elements.  `.val()` gets the value of the input element -- regardless of type. `.text()` gets the innerText (not HTML) of all the matched elements.

```
  setNumberFormattedInput: function (element) {
            var amount = s.toNumber(element.text.replace(/,/g, ''));
            if (!_.isNaN(amount)) {
                $(element).text(s.numberFormat(amount));
            } else {
                $(element).text(0);
            }
        },
    };
```